# Adding value to {count}

Tags: channel-entries, tags

How do I add a value to the {count} variable?

I'm trying to do this:

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='links' orderby='link_order' sort='asc' dynamic='no'  category='12'}
<div class="item" id="pane-{count+15}" style="display: none;">
    <!-- stuff here -->
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

I want the HTML to come out like this:

```
<div class="item" id="pane-16" style="display: none;">
    <!-- stuff here -->
</div>
<div class="item" id="pane-17" style="display: none;">
    <!-- stuff here -->
</div>
<div class="item" id="pane-18" style="display: none;">
    <!-- stuff here -->
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, EE is support calculations in conditions only. For other cases you can use [MX Calc](https://github.com/MaxLazar/mx-calculator)

```
{exp:channel:entries channel='links' orderby='link_order' sort='asc' dynamic='no'  category='12' parse="inward"}
<div class="item" id="pane-{exp:mx_calc expression='{count}+15'}" style="display: none;">
    <!-- stuff here -->
</div>
{/exp:channel:entries}
```

Comment: There are few math / calculation add-ons for EE ([search results](https://devot-ee.com/search/results?keywords=math&addon_version_support=ee2)), but MX Calc is most of the times choice #1